# Google. Найти фразу внутри одного предложения

Tags: google-search

Если написать:

`"мы переехали в новую квартиру вчера."`

То Google будет выдавать такие результаты:

`"мы переехали в новую квартиру! Вчера появился сдесь инет ..."`

А мне нужно чтобы целевая фраза была целиком внутри одного предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Используй для этого "амперсанд" `&`:

```
"мы & переехали & в & новую & квартиру & вчера"
```

Comment: нет результатов для `"мы & вчера & переехали & в & новую & квартиру"`

Comment: @Слоник ищи без `"`

Comment: Вот что выдает:
`Она переехала в новую квартиру вчера`
`Недавно переехали в новую квартиру. Вчера пошли с девушкой выгуливать собаку.`
А мне это совсем не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте применить разметку структурированными данными - **[руководство Гугл](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)** + библиотека **[Schema](http://schema.org/)**. Трудно давать конкретные рекомендации, т.к. не известна тема веб-сайта или конкретной веб-страницы. Но, вы можете применять такие общие свойства/атрибуты как, например: **description** `<span itemprop="description">мы переехали в новую квартиру вчера</span>` , или же, если на веб-странице уже имеется это свойство, то возможно применение свойства **[disambiguatingDescription](http://schema.org/disambiguatingDescription)** , как дополнение к имеющемуся описанию. Также вы можете применять свойства potentialAction с расширением/вложением для типа/класса **[Action](http://schema.org/Action)**. Обратите внимание, что внизу имеется много уточняющих типов этой разметки, большинство из которых, также имеют уточняющие свойства. Чем более точное свойство вы примените для содержания ваших веб-страниц, тем легче поисковики будут понимать ваш контент. Это также облегчает пользовательский поиск и повышает органический трафик на ваш веб-сайт.